# remove space from either side of br tag

Tags: php, preg-replace

Id like to know how you remove a space if it exists on either side of a `<br />` tag

```
$str = 'remov e <br /><br />from<br /><br /> r<br />'
```

i tryed the following but i cant get it fully working.

```
preg_replace('/[\s]<br \/>/', '', $str );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_replace(":\s*<br \/>\s*:mis", "<br />", $str);
```

Keep in mind that `\s` matches any white-space, including tabs and newlines - not just spaces `chr(20)`.

Comment: Thanks one othere thing, what is 
    :mis

Comment: They're modifiers - http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php `m` and `s` are for proper handling of newlines, `i` is for case insensitivity